# 'Invalid Signature' error for Access Token (azure active directory / msal js)

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I used MSAL JS for authenticating user & thereafter calling acquireTokenPopup(scopes) for Access Token.

I am getting the access token, but cannot use it as it says **Invalid Signature**. 
(checked in jwt.io too - same error)

Over the forum I found it is due to Graph adding nonce.
What will be the solution?
Please help.

Following is the code.

```
tenantConfig = {
    scopes: ["directory.read.all"]
};
```

this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(this.tenantConfig.scopes).then(
                function (accessToken) {

```
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                this.clientApplication
                    .acquireTokenPopup(this.tenantConfig.scopes)
                    .then(
                        function (accessToken) {

                            console.log("access token   " + accessToken);
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    );
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 8):

Your scopes parameter should be "[CLIENT_ID]/.default" When using MSAL.js and if you are not using graph api:

```
var requestObj = {
  scopes:["[CLIENT_ID]/.default"]
};
```

If you intent to use the graph api the scopes parameter is different:

```
var ResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net/";
var scopes = [ ResourceId + "Directory.Read", ResourceID + "Directory.Write"];
```

The example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa uses graph api and generate a specific token for graph api, change the scopes parameter if you need to generate an access token for other uses.

More information on scopes parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes#scopes-to-request-access-to-all-the-permissions-of-a-v10-application

Comment: This was not clear from any of the documentation. Once I switched out the scope to this, the token signature was accepted as valid. Don't know exactly why, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't matter. Just change the **algorithm** to `HS256` in jwt.io, then the signature will be verified.

[image]

The access token should be ok. Just make sure you have added **Diretory.Read.All** permission on Azure portal and granted admin consent.

[image]'

Reference:

[Call Graph API from a JavaScript Single Page Application using msal.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2)

Comment: But when decoding the token with jwt.io or jwt.ms it says the algorithm is RS256. Is MSAL.js encoding wrong?

Comment: It turns out the token is not wrong, it is just a specific token for graph api only. See my answer below.

Comment: This answer gets it to decode correctly in the decoder, but misses the general use-case of validating against Azure's metaidentity service. Juan Rojas' answer corrected my invalid signature issue per the OP's use case.