# React MSAL access token has invalid signature

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, react-typescript

### Setup

msal (in another file. Passed using `MsalProvider`):

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: <B2C-Application-ID>,
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-directory-id>",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    }
});
```

Import:

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";
import {EventType, InteractionStatus} from "@azure/msal-browser";

import React, {createContext, FC, useState} from "react";
import {useIsAuthenticated, useMsal} from "@azure/msal-react";
import {AuthenticationContextType} from "../@types/authentication";
import {EndSessionRequest} from "@azure/msal-browser/dist/request/EndSessionRequest";
import jwtDecode, {JwtPayload} from "jwt-decode";
```

Variables:

```
const {instance, accounts, inProgress} = useMsal();
const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
```

Login:

```
function loginRedirect() {
    instance.loginRedirect({
        scopes: ["User.Read"],
        prompt: "select_account"
    });
}
```

Acquire token:

```
function getToken(): string | null {
    if (token) {
        const decodedJwt = jwtDecode<JwtPayload>(token);
        if (decodedJwt.exp && decodedJwt.exp * 1000 > Date.now()) {
            return token; // Token is still valid
        }
    }

    // If token is not available or not valid anymore, acquire a new one
    if (instance.getActiveAccount() && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
        const accessTokenRequest = {
            scopes: ["User.Read"],
            account: accounts[0]
        }

        instance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(`access token: ${response.accessToken}`);
                console.log(`id token: ${response.idToken}`);
                setToken(response.accessToken);
                return response.accessToken;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (err instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                    return instance.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest)
                        .then(response => {
                            setToken(response.accessToken);
                            return response.accessToken;
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                        })
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
    } else {
        console.error("No account logged in to acquire token");
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Problem

I acquire two tokens (ID and access) from msal (see console logs). The ID token is being validated successfully (on my API and [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)) but my access token is not (neither on my API nor jwt.io). Referring to [this microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#token-types) I should use the access token to validate against an API.

As far as I can see, jwt.io does fetch the public key correctly from `https://sts.windows.net/<tenant-directory-id>/discovery/v2.0/keys`. This means [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816301/msal-access-token-invalid-signature) is either outdated, or doesn't solve my problem. To go sure I also tried to copy&paste the public key, which didn't work either.

I also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709423/invalid-signature-error-for-access-token-azure-active-directory-msal-js) which didn't work for me either. Changing the `scopes` leads to an endless login loop.

### Versions:

```
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.28.3",
"@azure/msal-react": "^1.4.7",
"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Scope

For requesting B2C access tokens you have to specify a valid scope. These are also set in Azure (Azure AD B2C -> App registrations -> `your application` -> Manage -> API permissions). There you have to specify a scope. While acquiring the tokens you have to specify these scopes like this:

```
const accessTokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<app-id>/<scope>"],
}

await instance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
    .then(response => {
        setIdToken(response.idToken);
        setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(async err => {
        if (err instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            await instance.acquireTokenPopup(accessTokenRequest)
                .then(response => {
                    setIdToken(response.idToken);
                    setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
```

`tenant-name` you can find this in the Application ID URI
`app-id` is your Application (client) ID
`your-scope` could be something like `Subscriptions.Read`

A full example for a scope could be:
`https://mydemo.onmicrosoft.com/12345678-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/Subscriptions.Read`

### 2. Invalid token version

For me the problem was `1. Scope` but maybe this does not solve the problem for others. Here is something else to try:

Following [this](https://jan-v.nl/post/2020/my-bearer-token-is-sts-windows-net-but-i-need-it-to-be-login-microsoftonline-com) article, the `sts` url is used vor the v1 endpoint. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003246#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute) claims:

> The endpoint used, v1.0 or v2.0, is chosen by the client and only impacts the version of id_tokens. Possible values for `accesstokenAcceptedVersion` are 1, 2, or null. If the value is null, this parameter defaults to 1, which corresponds to the v1.0 endpoint.

This means that the used endpoint (v2.0 in my case) affected only the id-token, which made it validate successfully. The access token was still v1 thus with no validated signature.

#### Solution

To change the version, `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` needs to be set to 2 inside the Manifest. It is located at portal.azure.com -> Azure AD B2C -> App registrations -> `your application` -> Manage -> Manifest:

```
{
    ...
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    ...
}
```

Save the changes and wait. For me it took several hours to wait for the change to be applied. And I had to apply solution `1. Scope` as well. After that, the `iss` of new tokens should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-directory-id>/v2.0` instead of the `sts`-uri

Answer (score 0):

To get a valid access token, with a valid signature, the only thing I had to do was to change scopes from `['User.Read']` to `['https://graph.windows.net/User.Read']`.

So now in React I do:

```
const accessToken = (
    await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ["https://graph.windows.net/User.Read"],
        account: account,
    })
).accessToken;
```

My app registration in Azure does have the `Microsoft Graph API` `User.Read.All` permission.

The JWT token then have `iss` `https://sts.windows.net/{tentantId}/` and `audience` `https://graph.windows.net`, but at least it has a valid signature when checking on https://jwt.io .

### Edit

Normally you don't want to use the Graph API like above. Instead you want to use your API. Go to the `Expose an API` section and add a scope, e.g., titled "user_read" or something like that. Then modify the code to use scopes ["{appUri}/{scope}"], e.g., like this:

```
const accessToken = (
    await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ["api://123456789-1234-1234-123456789/user_read"],
        account: account,
    })
).accessToken;
```

Or in my case, since my app URI was `https://myapp.mycompany.com` for some reason, i use `scopes: ["https://myapp.mycompany.com/user_read"]`. I believe the API has the `User.Read` permission by default. If you e.g., want to add other claims such as Group IDs, you either need to defined optional claims in the Token Configuration section, or add the `Group.Read.All (delegated)` permission in the API Permission section as well as the `user_read` scope as delegated. You can find it by going to the `My APIs` tab when adding API permissions.